# Should a MMORPG use encryption?

Tags: encryption

First of all,
**do those successful commercial MMORPGs use encryption for game data transmission**?

I got an impression that many developers tend to *not* use encryption, because it can not prevent reverse engineering for cheating and making private server, but **doesn't it effectively reduce the number of those**?

Encryption also impacts performance, even just a little.

Good encryption does prevent network sniffering and man-in-the-middle, **are these important for MMORPGs**?

How about **protecting chat messages for privacy concerns**?

How do you think?

PS: I'm talking about game data, not user/password, auth info need to be encrypted for sure.

Answer (score 11):

Encryption is a tool.  Make sure the tool fits the problem.

Encryption is useful for essentially three things: 1) 3rd party can't view data, 2) both parties are who they say they are, 3) data hasn't be modified.  None of those really apply here.  Remember the client is on the user (attacker) machine. If they modify the client it will gladly sign & encrypt any message they want.

The second thing to consider is the fact that the client has the keys and thus you should assume the attacker also has the keys.  Even if you use asymmetric encryption the client has the key to decrypt anything it receives.  If you send "private data" to the client an attack can find the key and decrypt it.

A good MMORPG (deisgned to make cheating difficult) should assume two things:
a) user/attacker can see any data sent to client (so don't send things to client you don't want user to see)
b) an attacker can send any possible command to the user (so don't rely on the client for security).

**In most MMORPG the client is little more than a dumb terminal with impressive graphics.**  All computation, error checking, and validation occurs server side.  The client doesn't determine is you hit or miss, nor does it determine how much damage.  The client simply tells the server "I am attack with item 382903128." or some other action (not result).  The server validates that the player has access to that option, has the item, and the command is valid at this time.  To prevent sniffing attacks the client is only given data that the user would have access to anyways.

Answer (score 6):

In any security context, you need to think about what exactly the threat scenarios are.

Attacker A has access to a machine running the game client and wants to write a bot to automate his actions so as to win battles easily.

Attacker B is eavesdropping on packets on a local network, with the aim of

- Stealing login credentials so as to play the game for free.
- Spying on player-to-player private chat, perhaps to gain advantage in the game, or maybe for blackmail or harassment in the real world.
- Inserting extra behaviour into the stream of commands, e.g. instructions to buy or sell items at prices that make money for the attacker.

Encryption has no effect on attacker A (since the game client can decrypt the communication, so can the attacker; counter-measures must be taken on the server) but defeats attacker B.

I disagree with some of the other answers about the value of the data being transmitted. Your private chats with other players are as worthy of protection as your instant messages with them, and your gold and possessions, earned with hours of toil, deserve *some* protection from attackers, if perhaps not as much as your dollars in a bank account.

Comment: The most annoying attacker is using a trojan on the victims computer. And it's very hard to protect against that.

Answer (score 2):

During the 90's Ever Quest used a low level packet encryption. I recall fondly as there used to be a side application that would sniff the packet data and give you a zone wide info about everyone in the zone. The EQ team crippled this for a while when they added the packet encryption, but that didn't stop the hacker community as they would just get the key out off the client machine. So in the end, it really didn't help in any way.
As to the other MMO's out there, I've not looked at the packet data to make a determination one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need encryption for security per se.

Consider this 'packet':

```
<USER_ID><COMMAND><MD5HASH>
```

The `MD5HASH` is generated from the `USER_ID` + `COMMAND` + some other value both the server and client know, but is not transmitted over the wire (user email or some token supplied securely during login). The server can reconstruct the string used for hashing and verify the authenticity of the command. If some man-in-the-middle changes the `COMMAND`, the hash won't match.

Besides validating authenticity this method also allows you to check you received the entire instruction. (It's possible that your 'game packet' is spread across multiple TCP/IP packets, some might get lost, etc.)

This does not prevent snooping around in messages, but is does prevent tampering. It's a game, who cares about what players say? I mean, emails are unencrypted and nobody cares about those, while their contents is more valuable than the average in-game chat.

Comment: Unless you include a message counter this is vulnerable to "replay attack"s. If an attacker repeats the "give ingame money to other person" command that's a serious threat.

Comment: This is another case of "Don't design your own security protocol" use one written by experts. And even experts get it wrong often enough.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption is always a good thing if it actually protects valuable data. For that would be bank data, mails, instant messaging and file transfers. Not because I'm terribly paranoid of my ISP or network provider, but there is a specific risk if you are in an open network (for instance, school networks or company networks), that someone might be reading sniffing network traffic.

For MMORPGS I don't see a benefit in either security nor in performance, since most data is highly session based and man-in-the-middle attacks are rather unlikely (because, afterall, *why* would you want to sniff and attack such a connection?).

What I would do is to transmit passwords and login credentials as hashed values (or even encrypt just that part), and leave the rest of the connection cleartext; so you don't suffer from CPU hogging and lag caused by encryption (especially when there is a heavy load on the server).

Comment: Logins secured with password hashing aren't that easy to implement correctly. So I'd rather use full blown public key crypto to prevent MITM. But of course crypto doesn't help against trojans.

Answer (score 1):

At least the login should be encrypted, and the client should verify the public key of the server against a white-list to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.

Encrypting the data transfered during the game itself isn't that important.

You need to distinguish encryption and obfuscation which have quite different goals.
For example SSL is useful as encryption but useless as obfuscation since the encryption happens in known APIs, and it's trivial to intercept the plaintext when it gets passing into/out from these APIs.
Obfuscation needs to be mixed into your own code and doesn't need to be cryptographically secure.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption needed vs administrators of local network or Wi-Fi, they potentially could sniff your traffic/packets and grab/change game information/passwords.

Tipically (99.99999%) accounts are hacked by trojans, not by packet sniffing. So in 99.99999% encryption is useless.

Encryption is totally useless vs Botting or Cheating. For that cases there is special forces, like - Anti-Cheating/Bot systems.